# Proof of consequences for ignoring dependence in clustered data

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, clustered-standard-errors

This may be a trivial question and apologies if it's been answered elsewhere.

I'm aware that violating the GM assumption of observations being independent, such as with clustered data, can result in estimates no longer being BLUE and that the correlation between observations within a given cluster (i.e. the intraclass correlation) can have negative down-stream effects for correctly estimating standard errors. What I'm hoping to get is a proof for why this is the case. I have this result from Liang and Zeger (1993):

[image]

but what isn't clear to me is *why* $V_2 = V_1[1 + \rho(n + \phi - 1)]$

Any help with better understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pardon my typo in the equation I wrote, it should be $V_2 = V_1[1 + \rho (n\phi - 1)]$

Comment: Welcome to cv, Ben Listyg - you can edit your question and stealthily remove the typo ;-)